# socket клиент не подключается к серверу в локальной сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Я хочу создать соединение между пк и смартфоном в локальной сети.

Код сервера (пк):

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('', 12345))
server.listen()
print("listening")

while True:
    user, address = server.accept()
    while True:
        data = user.recv(1024).decode("utf-8").lower()
        print(data)
```

... и клиента:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('196.168.0.109', 12345))
while True:
    client.send(input().encode("utf-8")
```

При запуске сервера в консоли пишется "listening" и дальше сервер ждет. Но при запуске клиента на телефоне нечего не происходит, даже ошибки.
P.S. Код клиента я запускал через Termux, а сервера — через Visual Studio Code.

Comment: А если запустить код клиента на сервере - происходит подключение?

Comment: если адрес локальный, то в нём, почти наверняка, опечатка: `196`, а не `169`... если это глобальный адрес, то расскажи подробнее о топологии своей сети...

Comment: Да, предыдущий комментарий - показывет возможную опечатку...

Comment: @S.H Да, происходит.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, локальный, но даже когда поменял, нечего не поменялось

Comment: @FanaticExplorer, проверь адрес своих машин — скорей всего там `192`, а не `196` — я тоже опечатался в прошлый раз... дальше проверь что с локальной машины всё работает, а потом удоставерься, что они в одной сети...

Comment: А в `server.bind` не нужно ли конкретный адрес указывать? Попробуйте там тот же адрес указать, к которому вы обращаетесь в другом скрипте.

Comment: Почему вы в server.bind() не вписали ip который пишете в client.connect()?
Также попробуйте вписать единицу в server.listen(1).